# Showing that a multivariable limit doesn't exist

Tags: analysis

[Showing that a multivariable limit exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999072/showing-that-a-multivariable-limit-exists/999116#999116)

With the same set up as the above question, I need to show that 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) \text{ does not exist.}
$$
I need to show that, given any $\delta$-ball around the origin (so open circles for us), there is a point $p \in A$ and a point $q \in A^c$. Then $|f(p)-f(q)|=1-0=1$. Thus if I pick any $\epsilon_0$ between $0$ and $1$, $|f(p)-f(q)| \geq \epsilon_0$, and the limit does not exist.

My problem is showing that we are guaranteed to have such a $p$ in every circle; it seems obvious geometrically, but showing so rigorously is hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{n},0)\to (0,0)$,$f(x_n,y_n)=0$,

Let $(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{3}{2n^2})\to (0,0)$,$f(x_n,y_n)=1$,

By sequential criterion, the limit doesn't exsit.

If you really want to use definition, just let $n$ large enough, you will get $p$ in the circle.

Comment: For limits in terms of sequences, don't we require that the sequence be in the set $A$? The first one is not in this set.

Comment: @Ducky If the limit exists, the limit should be the same no matter how x,y approaches (0,0).

Comment: Of course - my apologies. I got $A$ mixed up with the function's domain ($\mathbb{R^2}$ for us).